# Retrieve username from User table for each member in a Team

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm facing some issues in establishing relationships amongst User, Clan, and Clan Member models. I have three models in which I have defined the relationship as...

**Clan model**

```php
public function clanMembers() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ClanMember', 'clan_id', 'clan_id');
}
```

**ClanMember model**

```php
public function clan() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Clan', 'clan_id', 'clan_id');
}
```

I am trying to get Clan details of a requested user and his other Clan Members. I am using the following:

```php
$clanMembers = ClanMember::find(Auth::user()->id)->clan()->with('clanMembers')->get();
```

From the above, I am getting the response correct.

```json
"data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "clan_leader_id": 3,
            "clan_name": "@rockers1",
            "clan_avatar": "",
            "game_id": 1,
            "max_members_count": 50,
            "clan_id": "1505ccd15b01",
            "created_at": "2019-05-04 04:31:44",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-04 04:31:44",
            "clan_leader_name": "" 
            "clan_members": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "clan_id": "1505ccd15b01",
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "status": 0,
                    "created_at": "2019-05-04 04:33:03",
                    "updated_at": "2019-05-04 04:33:03"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Now I want to establish a relationship between the User and Clan model which has id and `clan_leader_id` as a foreign key to get `clan_leader_name` from User table in Clan model and `user_name` in place of `user_id` in `clan_members`. Clan member has `user_id` and id with the user as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships. Your models/tables should be: `User`, `Clan`, and `ClanUser`, where `clan_user` is an intermediate pivot table containing `clan_id` and `user_id`.

Your `Clan` model should contain the following relationship

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

And your `User` model should contain the following relationship

```
public function clans()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clan');
}
```

To get a list of clans for a user:

```
$clans = User::find($userId)->clans()->get();
```

To get a list of users for a clan:

```
$users = Clan::find($id)->users()->get();
```

Comment: I clan_leader_name in the above result set only, how to reach that

Comment: @NirnayKulshrestha define a [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) "leader" relationship on the clan model.